# What is the difference between the Explicit and Ignore attributes in nunit

Tags: .net, nunit

What is the difference between the `ExplicitAttribute` and the `IgnoreAttribute` in nunit?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are asking for Use cases: **When should i use `[Explicit]` and when `[Ignore]`**:

I use `[Explicit]`

- for long running tests that should not run every time. This guarantees fast execution of the testsuite.

I use `[Ignore]`

- for broken tests that i am currently fixing and
- as a kind of todo-list for tests that are not implemented yet

Answer (score 15):

> The Explicit attribute causes a test or test fixture to be ignored unless it is explicitly selected for running. The test or fixture will be run if it is selected in the gui, if its name is specified on the console runner command line as the fixture to run or if it is included by use of a Category filter.
>
> The ignore attribute is an attribute to not run a test or test fixture for a period of time. The person marks either a Test or a TestFixture with the Ignore Attribute. The running program sees the attribute and does not run the test or tests. The progress bar will turn yellow if a test is not run and the test will be mentioned in the reports that it was not run.

Check out the [NUnit Documentation](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=explicit&r=2.4.8)